# Calling a object function in boost scope exit

Tags: c++, boost, scope

I have the following piece of code:
How do I call a member function in scope exit.

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo();
    void bar();
};

void A::foo() 
{
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(void)
    {
        bar(); // Does not compile
    }
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
}

void A::bar() {}

void foo4()
{
    A a;    
    a.foo();
}
```

Err message

```
boost_scope_exit.cpp: In static member function ‘static void  
A::foo()::boost_se_guard_t_71::boost_se_body()’:
boost_scope_exit.cpp:73:13: error: cannot call member function ‘void          
A::bar()’ without object
     bar(); // Does not compile
         ^
```

How can I call a member function from scope exit.

Found a answer in the boost documentation:

[Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/scope_exit/tutorial.html)

Just search for "Capturing The Object this"

Comment: I haven't used `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT` but looking at the documentation, what I think you need is     `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&this)
    {
        this->bar();
    }
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work if you make bar static (and call A::bar()).
If that's not an option, it looks like you need to capture the this pointer
using the special symbol this_  (note the trailing underscore).

```
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(this_)
{
    this_->bar();  // note trailing underscore on this_
}
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
```

Comment: -> error: ‘this_’ was not declared in this scope; Seems to be dependent on version or compiler.